# Can't setup socket.io connection with the browser using nodejs

Tags: node.js, socket.io

I am getting a strange error when trying to set up a nodejs - browser socket.io connection.

I've migrated out the socket.io related code to a file, here it is:

```
import socketIO from 'socket.io';
import https from 'https';
import express from 'express';
import fs from 'fs';

var listener,
    io;

listener =  https.createServer({
    key: fs.readFileSync('/path/to/key'),
    cert: fs.readFileSync('/path/to/crt')
}, express());


listener.listen(3200, function() {
    console.log("Listening on 3200"); 
    io = socketIO(listener, {
      rejectUnauthorized: false,
      wsEngine: "ws"
    });

    io.on('connection', function(socket){
        console.log('a user connected');
      });
});
```

If I run this file with `node main.js`, the console outputs the following message:

> (node:615) ExperimentalWarning: The ESM module loader is experimental.
>   Listening on 3200

Now if I try to navigate with a browser to `https://my.domain.name:3200`, the browser outputs the following message:

> Cannot GET /

And no output is received from the node server.

What could be causing this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to create a web socket connection to https://my.domain.name:3200, not just go to the page. Try following https://socket.io/get-started/chat/, it will show how to serve a web page to make that connection from.